# formalizing the theory of real numbers

Tags: logic

Does anybody know what is the difference between the second order theory of the real numbers and the theory of the real numbers formalized in ZFC? Is any of them more expressive than the other?
Since the real numbers can not be axiomatized in FOL we have to use one of the solutions above. Which method do mathematicians use?

Comment: While I understand that this question is somewhat natural, it strikes me as a bit "too naive" and "too odd". So I have to ask, why do you ask, and I don't mean "I'm just curious" as an answer. I mean *really* why are you curious about the answer?

Comment: One of the reasons for asking this question is my lack of understanding of the differences between ZFC and second order logic/type theory. Second order logic is more expressive than first order logic but second order logic can be modelled in the First order theory of ZFC. The case of reals is just an example.

Comment: The natural numbers rather than the reals give a simpler example.I agree with Asaf that you should help us know what you are really interested in: as things stand, the answers to the three sentences above ending with a question mark are respectively: "yes", "yes (ZFC, assuming you mean 'expressi**ve**')", and "both (as well as lots of other approaches), depending on context".

Comment: "Which method do mathematicians use?" I don't think most mathematicians bother too much about these question. They take the real numbers for granted and that they have the properties that are expected of them.

Comment: Yes I meant expressive thank you. I have a lot of questions in my pocket. The original question could be formulated as "Is there a formula of the language of reals that is a logical consequence of the axioms formulated in ZFC but not a logical consequence of the axioms formulated in 2nd order logic" Is one of the theories a subset of the other? Does that question even make sense at all lol?

Comment: Jeah I think the question was a bit silly. I wrote it yesterday late on the bus and weren't thinking much about it while typing. Since the models of the real nubers are the same up to isomorphism the two methods for axiomatization are basically the same.

Comment: @MetaLogicianWannabe: It's not that silly. When I finish my answer you'll have quite some things to think about.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2356379/second-order-logic-as-the-basis-for-set-theory/) might also interest you.

Answer (score 7):

Since you're curious, here's a curious fact. The computable reals have exactly the same first-order theory as the 'real' reals. And for any real-world (engineering, physics, ...) application one needs (and can manipulate) only computable reals. So arguably we don't need anything more than the first-order theory practically speaking. More mathematically...
$
\def\eq{\leftrightarrow}
$

Notice that if you look carefully at the categorical second-order axiomatization of the reals, it has just one second-order axiom $X$ that states that every bounded set of reals has a least upper bound, but this axiom is useless unless you also have axioms that permit you to construct sets of reals. All $X$ can do by itself is to force the meta-system (say ZFC) to 'see' that all models of the second-order axiomatization are isomorphic, simply because $X$ 'invokes' the meta-system's viewpoint (namely to 'know' what are sets of reals). The meta-system is certainly going to be equivalent to a first-order one (and ZFC already is), because it must have a recursive set of rules, and hence if it is consistent then it has a countable model. So (in the words of *André Nicolas*) the problem of categoricity just gets transferred upwards.

To make it clearer, suppose you believe that ZFC is meaningful. Then you clearly believe that ZFC is consistent. Then by a proof in ZFC you believe that there is a countable model $M$ of ZFC. In $M$ you can find the set $R$ corresponding to the reals as given by a construction (existential statement) in ZFC. $R$ satisfies the second-order axiomatization of reals from the viewpoint of $M$, but $R$ only has countably many elements from the viewpoint of ZFC. Do you consider $R$ to be the reals? No, but what are the reals? You can't just say "as constructed in ZFC", since $M$ is a model of ZFC and $R$ is a model of your chosen axiomatization according to $M$.

Next you may try using second-order logic with Henkin semantics to axiomatize the real numbers, so that it is more 'independent' of the foundations. But then as mentioned above you need to add set-existence axioms to even be able to use the second-order supremum axiom $X$. What could you add? The obvious choice would be to permit construction of any set $\{ x : P(x) \}$ where $P$ is some $1$-parameter sentence over the language of real arithmetic. But would you allow $P$ to contain only first-order quantifiers?

If so, then the whole thing ends up reducing to (being conservative over) the first-order theory of the reals, because such constructions are equivalent to definitorial expansions, and the existence of the supremum of definable bounded sets of reals is a first-order schema that is true in the reals and hence in any model of its (complete) first-order theory.

If no, then you can construct $N = \{ n : \forall S\ ( 0 \in S \land \forall k\ ( k \in S \to k+1 \in S ) \to n \in S ) \}$ in the resulting theory $R_2$. Note that $R_2$ easily proves that $0 \in N$ and also that $\forall k\ ( k \in N \to k+1 \in N )$, so $R_2$ can carry out induction over natural numbers as follows. Given any $1$-parameter sentence $P$ such that $P(0) \land \forall n \in N\ ( P(n) \to P(n+1) )$, we can in $R_2$ construct $Q = \{ n : n \in N \land P(n) \}$ and prove that $0 \in Q \land \forall k\ ( k \in Q \to k+1 \in Q )$, and then prove that $\forall n \in N\ ( n \in Q )$ (by the definition of $N$), which gives $\forall n \in N\ ( P(n) )$. Thus $R_2$ interprets arithmetic. Note that $R_2$ has a proof verifier program, and hence $R_2$ is essentially syntactically incomplete, unlike the first-order theory of the reals.

But $R_2$ has a subtle issue of impredicativity, in that it can construct a set of objects defined using quantification over all sets of objects, including the one being defined. This circularity is precisely what led to Russell's paradox in naive set theory. So one could question whether $R_2$ is meaningful or not. Of course, ZFC proves that the reals (as constructed in ZFC) satisfy $R_2$, but ZFC is itself impredicative, so if you wish you can transfer that question upwards...

Comment: The direct answer to your question is that if you formalize and work with something in ZFC then of course you have access to the full power of ZFC, including transfinite induction among other things, and so it will be stronger than any ordinary interpretation of second-order theory of the reals, including $R_2$, because after all ZFC proves $\text{Con}(R_2)$, which $R_2$ cannot by what I've said above.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question! Your post was very informative. I really like these types arguments about the foundations. As I understand now a lot comes down to the meta theory of reals. We do not have to use the full potential of ZFC but we can still axiomatize the reals in second order. I accept all of those constructions you showed. Another question could be why do we use the standard construction of reals and not one you mentioned. Maybe analysis and probability theory are easier made by using the standard methods.

Comment: @MetaLogicianWannabe: Well, as I said I don't think you need anything beyond the first-order theory of the reals for all real-world applications. Also, I think almost all useful theorems of analysis are provable in a predicative second-order theory of reals, meaning not even $R_2$. However, if you already have some set theory or type theory, then you can easily construct reals via Cauchy sequences or Dedekind cuts, and so you would probably have $R_2$. But as you note this still depends on the meta-system's reals, which could well be predicative.

Comment: @MetaLogicianWannabe: To expand a bit on my last comment, one common predicative theory of arithmetic is ACA as described [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1808558/21820). One can take it further to predicative higher-order arithmetic in the natural way. This essentially gives a stratified type hierarchy so that all definitions are in essence well-founded, assuming we already have a fixed collection of natural numbers. By thinking of a real number as a (constructible) set of natural numbers in predicative higher-order arithmetic $A$, one can say that $A$ can do almost all real analysis.

Comment: Are you saying that the construction using Dedekind cuts or Cauchy sequences differ from the original second order construction?

Comment: @MetaLogicianWannabe: There is no such thing as an "original second-order construction", just as there is no such thing as an "original axiomatic construction of natural numbers". No matter what kind of axiomatization you use, it does not in itself make the structure exist (under the semantics for the chosen language). You could easily have an inconsistent axiomatization. Similarly, whatever axiomatization of reals (first-order or second-order) do not make the reals suddenly exist.

Comment: @MetaLogicianWannabe: Dedekind cuts and Cauchy sequences are the most common ways to construct the reals, but it is not a given that what you get from the construction has the properties you want, and you would still have to prove that it has each property one by one. The whole point of using an axiomatization rather than an explicit structure is that all the theorems that you prove from that axiomatization hold for any structure satisfying it. About axiomatization as an abstraction, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1809216/21820) and the one linked from there.

Comment: @MetaLogicianWannabe: Now first-order logic is very suitable for this purpose of abstraction, because you can work within the first-order theory, and every model of that theory will satisfy all your theorems. Second-order logic with full semantics is bad for this, because you need to work in the meta-system, and "model" will include the whole meta-system. A reasonable compromise is second-order logic with Henkin semantics, and $R_2$ is an example of this for axiomatizing reals. You still need to construct in the meta-system a structure and prove that it is a model of $R_2$.

Comment: @MetaLogicianWannabe: After that, you can happily work inside $R_2$, knowing that the theorems you prove will hold for any model of $R_2$, including the one you have constructed in the meta-system. If you want your work to be even more robust (more independent of the foundations), then you can opt for a more predicative axiomatization than $R_2$, such as predicative higher-order arithmetic, as sketched in my earlier comments, and you can prove most real analysis within it anyway. For further discussion, you're welcome to [the logic chat-room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44058/logic)!

Comment: As soon as I have got 20 points.

Comment: @MetaLogicianWannabe: Oh I forgot about that restriction; I'll ask a mod to give you access.

Comment: Just for reference, the conversation related to this post starts [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/44058?m=39268501#39268501).

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to ask how *mathematicians* as opposed to *logicians* deal with the real numbers, the answer tends to be on the side of set theory.  Thus, the classical construction using Dedekind cuts relies explicitly on subsets of the rationals, whereas the construction using equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences also involves set theory in justifying the quotient construction. In fact, a majority of mathematicians have trouble relating to the distinction between first and second order logic, and the fact that the familiar completeness axiom involves second-order quantification tends to surprise them.

Comment: I'm actually rather of the opinion that a theory in second-order logic (or higher-order logic) is really just a recipe for making a special kind of first-order theory... but often comes with the expectation that, in an interpretation, certain types are mapped to the power set or exponential of the interpretations of other types. (admittedly, I haven't stress-tested this opinion)

Comment: @Hurkyl, in the sense of Henkin semantics your comment is certainly borne out by the fact that the transfer principle enables quantification over internal sets, which is a kind of second-order quantification in disguise.  Is this the type of thing you were referring to?

Comment: I had in mind something more along the lines of axiomatizing some variety of type theory. I suppose what you describe could be considered an example of such a thing.

Comment: @Mikhail Katz Yes I have also noticed that they (majority of mathematicians) are not aware of these types of problems. I think this is because they are hardcore platonists and they think that truth is given and sets are abstract entities that exist independently from their minds. For them the existence of a countable model of the reals means that ZFC or logic or whatever can't express the properties of abstract reality well enough. Or they just don't care at all.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all of you for the answers. I have been thinking more about the problem of the different constructions of the real numbers lately. As we can see from the previous posts there are some very interesting possible constructions of the reals which are very similar to the "standard"(?) construction, in that they are the same from the perspective of first order logic. However some of the most important topics in the theory of reals are not first order. Namely the convergence of series. I think that the reason for the use of these second order axioms is that we can prove the existential theorems of analysis (e.g. existence of Lebesgue integral) for a wide set of objects and so we can do physics. Also some theories which use the reals become not-so-hard and not-so-ugly. (Theory of Hilbert spaces for example)
Sorry for my broken English I'm still learning the language.

edit: In Physics one only needs the computable reals but if we have a convergent sequence of computable reals the lim of this sequence can be uncomputable. So the nice theorems of analysis may not be true.

Comment: I really can't recall whether I told you this or not (so long ago!) but I'm quite sure we can recover practically all real-world mathematics if we use predicative higher-order arithmetic (ACA is predicative second-order arithmetic). Note that ACA already has all the finite Turing jumps, and any convergent sequence that is computable by the $k$-th jump has its limit computable by the $(k+1)$-th jump. So the intended model of ACA has the (encoded) reals closed under limits of constructible convergent sequences.